# how to read returned map values using key names outside a method - java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, hashmap

I am working on a selenium java script which would read data from an xml file. I have a read function which reads data from xml file and writes in to a map and that map data is returned.See below

```
public Map<String, String> read() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

        Map<String, String> testData = new HashMap<String, String>();
        File fXmlFile = new File("src/test/java/Blocks.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("blocks");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                NodeList childEls = eElement.getElementsByTagName("*");
                for (int i = 0; i < childEls.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element cElement = (Element) childEls.item(i);
                    String name = cElement.getTagName();
                    String value = cElement.getTextContent();
                    value = System.getProperty("qa." + name, value);
                    testData.put(name, value);
                }

            }
            System.out.println("array" + testData);
        }

        return testData;
    }
```

Now i am not sure how to access values in the map outside read function - my xml file has url, username, password and 30+ rows of application data.

I can access values inside the read function but not sure how to do it outside the read function.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: whats the issue? You are returning the map so you should be able to use it.

Comment: i am not sure how to access it . I tried testData.get(keyname) - keyname for url is server so i tried  String servername = testData.get(server); but it did not work ,gave me null pointer exception

Comment: before returning `testData` can you print the size or `testData`?

Comment: yes i can print testData - below is just a part of testData i printed array{dobyyyy=1980, debtname=Debt, annuitycapamt=1000, fsamt=10000, salary=100000, discgoalname=Milestone Goal, proppurcvalue=400000

Comment: if your map does not have `server` as key then it will return null. so after doing `serverName = testData.get("server");`  you have to do null check for  `serverName` .

Comment: my map has server as the key, i only pasted part of the data- i can see all the keys i want to use but still unable to access them outside read method

Comment: can you add the other part of the code in your question. how exactly you are calling and how your accessing the map. that would help us to find the solution.